# how to link a database item to a link

Tags: php, database

I am designing a system for a recruitment agency and have a search page where the "applicants" can search for a job and apply, the search results is structured:

```
-Job_Title
-Job_description
-Apply link
```

This is the same for every result. Code for the above mentioned:

```
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {                      
                  $title = $row['Adv_title'];
                  $description = $row['Adv_desc'];

                  echo "<h2><a href='#'> $title</a> </h2>";
                  echo "$description <br /> <br />";
                  echo"<a href='../View/applicationForm.php' class='link-button right'><span>Apply</span></a>";
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to make the **Apply link** go to each Jobs respective Application form. How can I make the link different for each advert or link the application form to  *Adv_title*  in the database?

Comment: Does each job not have an ID?

Comment: What is your Adv url?

Comment: @LukeOliff yes it does have an Id, but I dont want to show the Id to the "applicants".

Comment: When you say you don;t wan to show it to them, do you mean they should have no access whatsoever, or only that they shouldn't be able to see it casually?

Comment: @FaridMovsumov what do you mean by your question? sorry..

Comment: How you open specific job page in browser? What is url?

Comment: @Jaydee, The Id is the Primary key and is a Auto_Increment, so I cant see the point in displaying the Adv_id

Comment: @FaridMovsumov From search result it goes directly to the Appliction Form the url to the application form would be: itstudents.dut.ac.za/201308/View/applicationForm.php

Comment: So you don't mind the id being part of the link address, just not any text on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to identify each job in `applicationForm.php`, you need to pass a parameter that identifies each job via `$_GET`. **This parameter should be unique for each job**, so it could be the `id` field in database that you mention, or it could be the title, assuming that you are checking title uniqueness whenever you create a new job.

So, if you want to use `id`, your code would look like this (assuming that your field is named `id`):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {                      
     $title = $row['Adv_title'];
     $description = $row['Adv_desc'];
     $id = $row['id'];

     echo "<h2><a href='#'> $title</a> </h2>";
     echo "$description <br /> <br />";
     echo"<a href='../View/applicationForm.php?id=$id' class='link-button right'><span>Apply</span></a>";
```

If, for any reason, you don't want end users to view your ids, you can always [encrypt](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mcrypt.php) them before showing, and decrypt them in `applicationForm.php`.

Comment: I used your method and it seems like it is what I wanted, but now I have another question. How would I View this Application for that specific job?

Comment: If I am understanding what you say, you need is to add the job `id` to the form itself, via `<input type="hidden" name="job-id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>`, so when the user submits the form you have both user data and the job which he has applied to. Later you can get all applications for each job by `SELECT * FROM application_table WHERE job_id = :job_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {                      
                  $title = $row['Adv_title'];
                  $description = $row['Adv_desc'];
                  $id = $row['Adw_id'];
                  $link = "/$id/View/applicationForm.php";

                  echo "<h2><a href="$link"> $title</a> </h2>";
                  echo "$description <br /> <br />";
                  echo"<a href='../View/applicationForm.php' class='link-button right'><span>Apply</span></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In hyperlink tag give the value of the link to redirect to instead of #.
Like you have Adv_Title and Adv_desc field you will need to keep the link too and then you can fetch it and use it.

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {                      
              $title = $row['Adv_title'];
              $description = $row['Adv_desc'];
              $link=$row['Adv_link'];
              echo "<h2><a href="$link"> $title</a> </h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

if application from is different according to the job adv, you better should have a field in the database table to consider about different application form according to each Adv_title.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {                      
              $title = $row['Adv_title'];
              $description = $row['Adv_desc'];
              $id = $row['Adw_id'];

              //if $row['url_link'] is full url
              $link = $row['url_link']; // full link

              //if $row['url_link'] is just and identifier 
              // some conditions goes here 
                ......


              echo "<h2><a href="$link"> $title</a> </h2>";
              echo "$description <br /> <br />";
              echo "<a href=".$link.">link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to hide the id, you can set a server side session variable holding the current job id. And the pick it up on the page that generates the application form. ALternatively, just include it as part of the URL as manuelpedrera shows.